# Porting Solaris program to Linux [RelaxNg Validity error: Element ticket failed to validate attributes]

Tags: xml, relaxng

I am porting a module of code from Solaris to Linux. I get this error

element ticket: Relax-NG validity error : Element ticket failed to validate attributes

I am totally struck up and have no idea of what this error could be.. but I am sure this will not involve any code change.. please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that there is an XML document somewhere that is being validated against a Relax-NG schema; and in that document, an element named `ticket` is being found invalid because its attributes somehow don't match the schema.

So... you may need to look for XML config or input files related to your app, or related to a dependency app. Possibly the version of the XML document on Solarix (Solaris?) used a different version of the Relax-NG schema than the version on Linux.

If you want help determining specifically how the XML failed to validate, you'd need to post the content of the offending XML document, and its Relax-NG Schema (or better, the relevant pieces thereof).